# Angular Js - ng-repeat over array of array objects

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I Have an Array that each member of it is, an array of objects. More detail: [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZmdL.png)
I want to use objects in ng-repeater. How do I do this?!

Comment: use nested ng-repeat

Answer (score 2):

You can use nested ng-repeat for this.

```
$scope.storeCar = [
  [ {name: 'abc'}, {name: 'def'} ],
  [ {name: 'ghi'}]
];
```

And iterate over storeCar like this:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="cars in storeCar">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="car in cars">
        {{car.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @HosseinGanjyar so if it doesn't work, could you insert source code of your storeCar object?

Comment: My data isn't it. my data is array of arrays object. please check picture in above question.

Comment: @HosseinGanjyar please insert sample of your structure in above jsfiddle and send link upgraded version

Comment: my datat is in [Link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KZmdL.png) . An array with arrays of objects. I want to show object in a repeater. thanks

Comment: @HosseinGanjyar so it's the same with the one I provided above... check my jsfiddle or insert real json data of your object, a code not a picture

Comment: @HosseinGanjyar you have to update jsfiddle after that and provide new url

Comment: @HosseinGanjyar your code has broken syntax. I fixed it and updated here https://jsfiddle.net/ew3f33oc/7/ and it's working. Array of arrays of objects should look like: `[ [ {}, {}, {}], [ {}, {}, {}] ]` and you have missing parent brackets and comma between.

Comment: Thanks a lot. A problem is here. I push data in this way:
https://jsfiddle.net/ecbg490f/
I can not change that to [ [ {}, {}, {}], [ {}, {}, {}] ]. Now, what to do?!

Comment: @HosseinGanjyar  I don't know, I think this is material for another question.